# Escutar um evento em cookies

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, cookies

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para ser usada em duas abas do navegador. Eventualmente uma aba modifica um cookie, logo, preciso efetuar um refresh na outra aba para carregar as informações corretas. Dessa forma é possível escultar um change num cookie, para que eu possa dar refresh na outra aba?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outras sugestões são bem-vindas.

Comment: Para isto, recomendo fortemente o localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage

Comment: @PauloRoberto é possível escultar eventos com localStorage?

Comment: da uma lida nesta pergunta e as respostas https://stackoverflow.com/q/26974084/2319589

Answer (score 1):

Não, não é possível. Não há API nativa para isso. E em geral é má prática depender de comunicação entre abas.

Se você precisa observar mudanças em cookies, talvez você possa usar [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) para ler os cookies de vez em quando. Assim você pode ver se houve alterações e tomar uma decisão sobre o que fazer baseado nisso.

Comment: O ruim do *setInterval* é que pode degradar a performance. Uma pergunta, porque é uma má prática depender da comunicação de abas? ps minha comunicação é com servidor.

Comment: Você não tem garantia de que a página na outra aba é realmente a página que você quer/precisa, o controle de sessões é complicado, você precisa sincronizar processos (abertura para race conditions), o suporte nativo para isso é paupérrimo...

Comment: com a chegada do `localStorage` o cookie ficou meio depreciadão :P

Comment: mas sim, daria pra fazer um **heartbeat** escutando o valor de *x* e armazenando o valor de *x* e quando o valor for diferente do armazenado faça algo. No caso o *x* seria o valor do cookie/ou oq for.